# Get values from the selected inputs and returns a shortcode

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery 100+ case around which are as follows where I want to compress or write in Object oriented.

```
var shortcode = {
    init: function () {
    jQuery('.primary_select select').change(function () {
        jQuery('.secondary_select').hide();
        if (this.value != '') {
            if (
              jQuery('#secondary_' + this.value).show()
              .children('.tertiary_select')
              .size() == 0) {
                 jQuery('#secondary_' + this.value).show();
            }
        }
    }).change();

    jQuery('#sendtoeditor').click(function () {
        shortcode.sendToEditor();
    });

    jQuery('.secondaryselect select').change(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.secondary_select')
        .children('.tertiary_select').hide();
        if (this.value != '') {
            jQuery('#atp-' + this.value).show();
        }
    }).change();
},
generate: function () {
var type = jQuery('.primary_select select').val();

switch (type) {
    case 'dropcap':
    var type            = jQuery('[name="dropcap_type"]').val();
    var text            = jQuery('[name="dropcap_text"]').val();
    var text_color      = jQuery('[name="dropcap_textcolor"]').val();
    var bgcolor         = jQuery('[name="dropcap_bgcolor"]').val();
    var droptype        = jQuery('#dropcap_type').val();

    if ( type )     { type = ' type="' + type + '"'; }
    if ( text )         { text = ' letter="' + text + '"'; }
    if ( text_color )   { text_color = ' text_color="' + text_color + '"'; }
    if ( bgcolor )      { bgcolor = ' bgcolor="' + bgcolor + '"'; }

    if(droptype == 'dropcap3'){
        return '[dropcap'+ type + text_color + text +']';
    }else{
        return '[dropcap'+ type + bgcolor + text_color + text +']';
    }
break;

case 'icons':
    var style = jQuery('[name="icons_icon"]').val();
    var size = jQuery('[name="icons_size"]').val();
    var color = jQuery('[name="icons_color"]').val();
    if (style !== '') {
        style = ' style="' + style + '"';
    }
    if (size !== '') {
        size = '  size="' + size + '"';
    }
    if (color !== '') {
        color = ' color="' + color + '"';
    }

    return '\n[icons' + style + size + color + ']\n';
break;
default:
    return extra();
    }
},
sendToEditor: function () {
    send_to_editor(shortcode.generate());
}
}
```

Let me put it this way, I have all the input name attributes with the values prefixed with the case type suffixed with its unique names like type, text, color etc.
I want to compress it something like this

```
case 'dropcap':
    var type, text, text_color, bgcolor;
    jQuery('[name="+'case'+_var"]').val();

    var droptype        = jQuery('#dropcap_type').val();

    if ( var )  { var = ' var="' + getvalue + '"'; }

    if(droptype == 'dropcap3'){
        return '[dropcap'+ type + text_color + text +']';
    }else{
        return '[dropcap'+ type + bgcolor + text_color + text +']';
    }
break;
case 'icons':
    var style,size,color;
    if ( var )  { var = ' var="' + getvalue + '"'; }

    return '\n[icons' + style + size + color + ']\n';
break;
```

Is this a good practice to do or is there a better way to do this?
How do I compress the above code?

Comment: It seems you could follow a convention of names in the inputs, in the form of "case_type", "case_text", etc. where 'case' is each option of the case (e.g.: if dropcap, the input name would start with "dropcap_..."). You could then build the selector automatically, saving you the effort of a case.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the attribute names in an array as a class array and loop through them. Here I've adapted my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35876215/2346308) on another question of yours to your whole class:

```
var shortcode = {
    allTypeAttributes: {
        'dropcap': ['type', 'text', 'text_color', 'bgcolor'],
        'icons': ['style', 'size', 'color']
    },

    init: function () {
        $('.primary_select select').change(function () {
            $('.secondary_select').hide();
            if (this.value != '') {
                if (
                    $('#secondary_' + this.value).show()
                        .children('.tertiary_select')
                        .size() == 0) {
                    // TODO: show() is already called in the if statement... fix it!
                    $('#secondary_' + this.value).show();
                }
            }
        }).change();

        $('#sendtoeditor').click(function () {
            this.sendToEditor();
        });

        $('.secondaryselect select').change(function () {
            $(this).closest('.secondary_select')
                .children('.tertiary_select').hide();
            if (this.value != '') {
                $('#atp-' + this.value).show();
            }
        }).change();
    },
    generate: function () {
        var type = $('.primary_select select').val(),
            typeAttributes = this.allTypeAttributes[type];

        if (typeAttributes !== undefined) {
            return this.createShortcode(type, typeAttributes);
        } else {
            return extra();
        }
    },
    createShortcode: function (name, typeAttributes) {
        var value;
        $.each(typeAttributes, function (id, attrib) {
            value = $('[name="' + name + '_' + attrib + '"]').val();
            if (value !== '') {
                ret += ' ' + attrib + '="' + value + '"';
            }
        });
        return '\n[' + name + ret + ']\n';
    },
    sendToEditor: function () {
        send_to_editor(this.generate());
    }
}
```

Maybe you could return an array from createShortcode instead of the string and send it to the editor? And there seems to be a bug, I've marked it with a `TODO`.

And as mentioned before, if your DOM is big, you should think about [selector optimisation](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/). It will also help limiting the scope before selecting on element names:

```
jQuery('.inputContainer').find('[name="icons_' + attrib + '"]')
```

Comment: I have few shortcodes with its ending code as well. like ` [shortcode]extra content goes here [/shortcode]` and some are like self closer without ending ` [divider] `. If you want you can check my full shortcode.js file here. [Shortcodes JS](http://snippi.com/s/a04zbeb)