# Build a selector automatically from inputs attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a generator something like a website builder where I am fetching the values from the name attributes of inputs fields and sending that to the editor. I don't know how to write the code and make it more clean.

```
case 'icons':
  var style = jQuery('[name="icons_icon"]').val();
  var size = jQuery('[name="icons_size"]').val();
  var color = jQuery('[name="icons_color"]').val();
  if (style !== '') {
    style = ' style="' + style + '"';
  }
  if (size !== '') {
    size = '  size="' + size + '"';
  }
  if (color !== '') {
    color = ' color="' + color + '"';
  }

  return '\n[icons' + style + size + color + ']\n';
break;
    case 'googlefont':
        var font    = jQuery('[name="googlefont_font"]').val();
        var size    = jQuery('[name="googlefont_size"]').val();
        var margin  = jQuery('[name="googlefont_margin"]').val();
        var text    = jQuery('[name="googlefont_text"]').val();
        var weight  = jQuery('[name="googlefont_weight"]').val();
        var extend  = jQuery('[name="googlefont_extend"]').val();
       // fontstyle is a checkbox
        var fontstyle   = jQuery('[name="googlefont_font_style"]');
        var color   = jQuery('[name="googlefont_color"]').val();

        if ( font )     { font = ' font="' + font + '"'; }
        if ( size )     { size = ' size="' + size + '"'; }
        if ( margin )   { margin = ' margin="' + margin + '"'; }
        if( weight )    { weight = ' weight="' + weight + '"'; }
        if( extend )    { extend = ' extend="' + extend + '"'; }
        if ( text )     { text = '' + text + ''; }
        if ( color )    { color = ' color="' + color + '"'; }
        if (fontstyle.is(':checked')) {
            fontstyle = ' fontstyle="true"';
        } else {
            fontstyle = ' fontstyle="false"';
        }

        return '[googlefont' + font + size + margin + weight + color + extend + fontstyle + ']' + text + '[/googlefont]';
        break;
    case 'drop cap':
       // type is a select element with the values
        var type            = jQuery('[name="dropcap_type"]').val();
        var text            = jQuery('[name="dropcap_text"]').val();
        var text_color      = jQuery('[name="dropcap_textcolor"]').val();
        var bgcolor         = jQuery('[name="dropcap_bgcolor"]').val();
        var droptype        = jQuery('#dropcap_type').val();

        if ( type )         { type = ' type="' + type + '"'; }
        if ( text )         { text = ' letter="' + text + '"'; }
        if ( text_color )   { text_color = ' text_color="' + text_color + '"'; }
        if ( bgcolor )      { bgcolor = ' bgcolor="' + bgcolor + '"'; }

        if(droptype == 'dropcap3'){
            return '[dropcap'+ type + text_color + text +']';
        }else{
            return '[dropcap'+ type + bgcolor + text_color + text +']';
        }
        break;
```

The above code is working fine but what if i have more fields in another case which has more than 30 input fields. I want to make the code compressed like this.

```
case 'icons':
  var style,size,color;
  if ( var )  { var = ' var="' + getvalue + '"'; }
  return '\n[icons' + style + size + color + ']\n';
break;
```

Or is there any more better way it can be handled.

**Updated**

Updated the code now dropcap and icons works fine but the google font case shows a problem that it don't take the values from the checkbox as there are no default values stored in input.

```
        case 'dropcap':
            var dropcapAttributes = ['type', 'text', 'textcolor','bgcolor'],
                ret = '', value;

            jQuery.each(dropcapAttributes , function (id, attrib) {
                value = jQuery('[name="dropcap_' + attrib + '"]').val();
                ret += ' ' + attrib + '="' + value + '"';
            });

            return '\n[dropcap' + ret + ']\n';
        break;
        // G O O G L E   F O N T
        //--------------------------------------------------------
    case 'googlefont':

        var googlefontAttributes = ['font', 'size', 'margin','text','weight','extend','font_style','color'],
            ret = '', value;

        jQuery.each(googlefontAttributes , function (id, attrib) {
            value = jQuery('[name="googlefont_' + attrib + '"]').val();
            ret += ' ' + attrib + '="' + value + '"';
        });

        return '\n[googlefont' + ret + ']' + text + '[/googlefont]\n';
        break;
    case 'icons':
         var iconAttributes = ['style', 'size', 'color'],
             ret = '', value;

         jQuery.each(iconAttributes , function (id, attrib) {
             value = jQuery('[name="icons_' + attrib + '"]').val();
             if(value !== '') {
               ret += ' ' + attrib + '="' + value + '"';
             }
         });

         return '\n[icons' + ret + ']\n';
         break;
```

In Google font the shortcode has an ending element and the text inside in it and it shows undefined. How do i separate the text attribute or any attribute from that?

Comment: Don't select the elements by their name, it will result in poor performance; Use ID's or classes instead.

Comment: @FabianH., don't prematurely optimize attribute selectors. They run fast enough and would only be problematic if your site has other deeper problems, like too many elements.

Comment: I have already developed this and i have more than 80 cases so the javascript now lines about 3000+ lines so worried about the performances and i want to make it more compress and faster as well.

@FabianH. Its good to have the Id's or classes, will consider using that too. But I don't know much about the jQuery, I'm a beginner in jQuery.

Comment: Using a loop, or literally typing each case, does nothing for performance, it's just shorter to write and saves you a few bytes, and maybe half a millisecond when loading the script. If you really wanted to make it faster, you'd use ID's and `document.getElementById('name_icon').value` etc.

Comment: The question was not about performance, but as @Maqk asked for advices, I've mentioned this aspect as well.

Comment: And just to note it, jQuery does have methods that create params or serialized strings, for instance `$(':input').serialize()` would work if the inputs have a name and value.

Comment: @adeneo - I think serializing will sanitize the values but will not the values be changed which i want to send to the editor?

Comment: Why would the values be changed? It looks like you're manually trying to create a querystring, and that's generally not neccessary at all.

Comment: Consider using [the `CSS.escape(...)` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) to ensure that any dynamic components of selector expressions are properly encoded.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Its good point to have sanitise the code but I think that is not a cross browser compatible. If i use it then i have to make it compatible for all the major browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the attribute names in an array and loop through them:

```
    case 'icons':
        var iconAttributes = ['style', 'size', 'color'],
            ret = '', value;

        $.each(iconAttributes , function (id, attrib) {
            value = jQuery('[name="icons_' + attrib + '"]').val();
            if(value !== '') {
              ret += ' ' + attrib + '="' + value + '"';
            }
        });

        return '\n[icons' + ret + ']\n';
        break;
```

Comment: H - That seems to be working fine, thanks but It isn't work when i have select and checkbox case. I have updated the code with that switch case type.

Comment: JQuery's `val` should also work with `<select>` and checkboxes: https://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I just added a modified code in an answering post. What am I doing wrong? I have selected the case for the color but not works sometimes.

Comment: I just realised i was taking wrong name in an array textcolor instead text_color

Comment: If you use the loop multiple times, you could swap it out into a function and pass it the needed variables (the attributes array and the prefix).

Comment: I have no idea about how to swap it into a function. If you want you can check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799265/get-values-from-the-selected-inputs-and-returns-a-shortcode) i have posted with a detailed code of how am using it. But that post is similar but what i want is different there.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it is useful to some extent. If you can see my updated code and reply me on that googlefont case It would be appreciable